# Would it be a security risk to create an Automator application to start Plone?

Tags: plone, zope, bin, sudoers

In order to make a "one-click" start-up solution for Plone on a dedicated Mac web server, I would like to create an Automator application. The purpose of this would be so that it can be launched on login so that if the computer encountered a power outage or needed to restart for maintenance, Plone would automatically start once the machine was powered on again. That said, because the installation would be as root, the user and ".../zeocluster/bin/*" would need to be blessed in sudoers in order to run without needing a password to start plonectl.

Basic question: is it a huge security risk on a production server to add /bin/* to sudoers?

Answer (score 1):

Zope will *start* as root, but will not *run* as root. After attaching to the port, it changes to the effective user specified in your buildout.

That said, unless you need to bind to a privileged port (like port 80 or 443), I would try to avoid starting Zope as root. It's just not necessary, and it increases the attack surface. For much the same reason, I'd avoid using automator for an app that starts as root.

Instead, take a look at the [init_scripts](https://github.com/plone/Installers-UnifiedInstaller/tree/master/init_scripts/OS_X) directory in the Unified Installer. It has example startup scripts and packaging lists for OS X. These haven't been touched in a long time, so there's a good chance you'll need to edit to match the actual start commands. I'd also have it sudo to the effective user rather than start as root. So:

```
sudo -u plone_daemon /usr/local/Plone/zeocluster/bin/plonectl start
```

Adjusted to your install location.